# Windows 8 installation, missing drivers

Tags: windows-8-preview

I would like to install Windows 8 on a PC without DVD or CD rom, so I made a bootable stick. The Windows 8 Customer Preview was downloaded from the Microsoft's site. When the install starts, after selecting the language it tells me "No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click OK." I've downloaded the Windows 8 driver install kit from the MSDN site, and tried to rescan again, but it doesn't work.

Could you suggest me some ideas, what to do now?

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: I've mentioned it in the question: "No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click OK." This is the exact error message.

Comment: Just making sure, I see you found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears to arise when the downloaded ISO is corrupt or incomplete. Have you tried downloading it again/double checking the file size with those on the website?