# Missing drivers installing Windows 8 PRO (USB stick)

Tags: windows-8, installation, drivers

I searched for a similar question and I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/416664/windows-8-installation-missing-drivers) although that one is talking about a Windows 8 Preview version. I recently bought a Windows 8 PRO license and I was given a link to download it. After I download that exe file (around 6MB) it ask if I want to install in the system, create a media or just the ISO. I tried to create the media from several computers and when I try to install it in the computer via USB (I don't have DVD), it always says that there are some missing drivers.

Any ideas how can I create a bootable USB installer for Windows 8 PRO?

I don't remember all the specs from my computer but I know it has an Intel Core 2 4400 2GHz, 4GB RAM, NVidia graphics, There's no other PCI connected to the motherboard.

It's worth mentioning that I had Windows 8 PRO installed in that computer before, but it suddenly stopped working and that's why I want to reinstall it again. Last time the same thing happened with the drivers but I have no idea why after a while it skipped itself the missing drivers part (I tried leaving now the computer on that screen again but no luck).

Comment: The process your using is the suggested way to create a bootable USB image of the installer.

Comment: @Ramhound I know, but because I keep on getting that error I was wondering if I can do it in any other way just to try. "Downvoter" please leave a comment about your vote. I'll appreciate it.

Comment: The problem stims from the iso being corrupt.  Are you pausing the download or something?

Comment: @Ramhound no.. and I have a quite fast broadband (30Mbps). And it happened the same when I used a friend's computer to download it.

Comment: So you had Win8 Pro installed before, it stopped working and you bough a fresh copy to reinstall? Why don't you simply [Reset your PC](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IWhHN.png) from the [Advanced Startup Options](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm)?

Comment: @Karan I had the license since the first install.. I tried recover from older point. I tried refresh and also Reset.. Nothing work, that's why I want to reinstall on top of it.

Comment: Even Reset did not work? Strange... Yeah I guess a clean install is in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was with the USB stick. I downloaded again the installer from Microsoft, installed in 2 different USB sticks, and the other keep on having the same Driver's problem, but the second USB stick I tried worked with no issues.

Comment: Right. I had the very same issue, and I solved by installing from DVD rather than from USB.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the ISO and then use Microsoft's [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) to "burn" it to a USB drive.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later and then I'll check the ISO file with this : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/where-i-find-the-correct-sha1-checksum-for-the/3cc1ce41-b6bb-4b2c-a95c-9cc54dd5d83b

Answer (score 0):

Just download the ISO of the Pro version of Windows 8 and use your key to activate it.

Please provide some additional information about your PC.

Comment: Thanks from your answer @Sanny-sin If I download the iso, how can I put in the USB memory to boot from it? is there any tool for that?

Comment: @SERPRO - The Upgrade Assistant is the tool you should be using.  If you want an alternative the Windows 7 tool also works with any Windows 8 iso.